# Grafana Combine By Alias

Tags: metrics, graphite, grafana

I have an graphite query with multiple template variables. When I combine multiple branches, I get multiple aliases of the same name. If there a way to combine via sum into one metric by the alias name?

This is the query that I have:

```
aliasByNode(graphs.$site.items.$item.*.job.queued, 6)
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm silly! Use group by node. All good!

Example:

```
groupByNode(graphs.$site.items.$item.*.job.queued, 6, 'sum')
```